# SQL Server query to find rows that have no parent and child in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Invoices 
(
    [InvoiceCode] varchar(20), 
    [ParentInvoiceCode] varchar(20),
    [InvoiceDate] date 
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Invoices
VALUES
( 'INV-001', 'INV-001', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-002', 'INV-001', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-003', 'INV-001', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-004', 'INV-004', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-005', 'INV-005', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-006', 'INV-006', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-007', 'INV-007', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-008', 'INV-007', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-009', 'INV-007', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' ),
( 'INV-010', 'INV-007', N'2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' )
```

As you see there are values 4,5,6 having no parent or child rows. What query can I use to find these?

Comment: Why do they have themself as parent? Wouldn't it make more sense to have the value `NULL` if they don't have a parent?

Comment: Why are your invoice numbers strings? Is the maximum number of invoices possible only 999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is just a simple `not-exists` query:

Find me all the rows where the `code` and `parentcode` are the same, but where there does not exist a different `parentcode` for these rows.

Also note that you cannot have more than 999 invoice codes and still be able to order them, the code and parent code should be `integer` columns. Otherwise when you want to add `INV-1000` it will be considered *less* than `INV-999` because these are *strings*!

```
select * 
from invoices i
where i.ParentInvoiceCode = i.InvoiceCode
    and not exists (
        select * from invoices i2
        where i2.ParentInvoiceCode = i.InvoiceCode 
            and i2.InvoiceCode != i2.ParentInvoiceCode
    )
```